# ¿Cómo traducir al español "more hype than substance"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

No logro encontrar una traducción a la frase **more hype than substance**. Tengo entendido que **hype** puede referirse a cuando alguien se emociona demasiado. Pero no comprendo toda la frase.

Este es el contexto que se maneja:

> Many companies that once considered Java to be **more hype than substance**
>   are now using it to create...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una expresión muy española:

> **[Mucho ruido y pocas nueces](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WoW1aWq#3YJYELC)**
>
> 1. expr. coloq. U. para señalar que algo aparentemente importante tiene poca sustancia o es insignificante.

En el caso de tu ejemplo:

> Muchas empresas que una vez pensaron que Java era mucho ruido y pocas nueces lo están usando ahora para crear...

Lo que yo entiendo como *hype* es cuando un producto se publicita de forma que genera demasiadas expectativas entre los consumidores incluso antes de ponerse a la venta, corriendo el riesgo de no llegar a cumplir dichas expectativas en el momento de su lanzamiento. Considero que el dicho español refleja esa sensación a la perfección, dado que una publicidad excesiva o demasiado optimista no hace más que crear ruido alrededor del producto.

La noticia parece tener que ver con este gráfico:

[image: Ciclo de sobreexpectación]

[De [IOTpreneur](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:IOTpreneur) - Trabajo propio, [CC BY-SA 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Enlace](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=42438606)]

Parece que el comentario de que Java era mucho ruido y pocas nueces se debió producir durante el abismo de desilusión, para luego entrar las empresas en esa fase llamada "meseta de productividad" tras darse cuenta de que el producto no era tan malo, sino que simplemente la expectativa previa se había sobredimensionado.

Sobre el uso de la expresión, la primera aparición que encuentro en el CORDE es del siglo XVII, lo que la convierte en una expresión con solera:

> *Y también sabe V. S. que todos los años es tan ordinario el mucho ruido de armada del Turco, como las pocas nueces de él, [...].*
>
> Diego de Amburcea, "Carta a Esteban de Ibarra", 1608 (España)

Comment: ¡Había pensado la misma expresión! Un gráfico similar se puede ver en el [uso de Documentation de Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339440/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui es parecido, pero no diría que es el mismo. El que enlazas carece del abismo de desilusión, simplemente hay un pico inicial causado por la novedad y luego el uso se estabiliza. Pero mola. Lo malo es que a veces esa "meseta de productividad" puede equivaler a "la gente lo ha dejado de usar", que es lo que parece preocupar en la pregunta enlazada.

Comment: Sí, cierto, de hecho el debate actual sobre _Documentation_ es si va a entrar en la rampa de consolidación o si va a caer en el desuso. De momento está en una especie de "meseta de desilusión" :)